# Under what scenarios can you use transitive verbs with に？

Tags: particle-に, transitivity

> 1. それじゃあなんかお前の方が詳しそうだから、ここはお前に任せる
> 2. 俺の負けだ。今日のところは素直に敗北を認める

Can に and を be swapped in these scenarios? If not, what is the distinction between 認める and 任せる ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, `ここはお前に任せる`, お前 is an indirect object (or dative) of 任せる, thus it is marked by に, the direct object (ここ) is marked by は (and は absorbed を).

In the second case, `敗北を認める`, 敗北 is the direct object of 認める, thus it is marked by を.

Comment: what would you say about this sentence? [何気に相手にも優しい誘い方ではあるな] - "well actually, this is also a kind way of (asking her out)".   相手に誘う alone can't be correct, so it is it also something like 何気に（デートは/を）相手にも優しい誘い方?

Comment: Actually, it is not 相手に誘う but 相手に優しい. see definition 4 [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%84%AA%E3%81%97%E3%81%84-648190)

Comment: I see thanks , what about [#6 「人によくかみつく犬」「友人に伝える」](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/166083/meaning/m0u/) . What makes かみつく and 伝える different?

Comment: In both examples に is a dative marker. Neither 人 nor 友人 are direct objects.

Comment: I'm sorry,　i don't quite understand. 動作・作用の行われる対象・相手を表す = Indicates the object/target of an action ? If Neither 人 nor 友人 are direct objects, what is?

Comment: Those are indirect objects. This quite visible on the example 友人に[何かを]伝える where the direct object (what is transmitted) is omitted. Things get a bit blurry with 噛み付くbecause the object is always marked by に with that verb.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83713/discussion-between--and-charu).